# Send video data to server from Objective-C client

Tags: objective-c, sockets, video-streaming, avfoundation, video-capture

I'm looking to send data from the webcam of a client Mac application to a server application currently written in Java (but this could change if there was a good reason).

I am using AVFoundation and have the following handler to handle new frames coming in from the webcam:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {

    CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);

}
```

What i'm looking for is how to send this data to my server over a socket that I have open. This should be a real-time feed, so I think I will need compression of the video and then to uncompress it at the server. If this is the case, are there particular libraries I should be using to do this?

I'm not really sure where to start with this and would appreciate some help.

Thanks